# Edit was rejected even though it doesn't copy from an external source

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I saw [this edit which I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27816341) to the tag [tkinter-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter-button). A bit of context: this tag refers to the `tkinter.Button` class and can be used to add a button to a parent widget.

I've been using tkinter for 5 years and have made a few games and applications with it. I'm not an  expert, but it's fair to say that I know what I am talking about when I talk about tkinter.

This is the text I added to the tag wiki:

> The Button widget is a standard Tkinter widget used to implement various kinds of buttons. Buttons can contain text or images, and you can associate a Python function or method with each button. When the button is pressed, Tkinter automatically calls that function or method.

Now that was a month ago and looking back I maybe could have worded it better, but my main confusion lies in why it was rejected for plagiarism. Just to double check I even did a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+Button+widget+is+a+standard+Tkinter+widget+used+to+implement+various+kinds+of+buttons.+Buttons+can+contain+text+or+images%2C+and+you+can+associate+a+Python+function+or+method+with+each+button.+When+the+button+is+pressed%2C+Tkinter+automatically+calls+that+function+or+method.&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS935US935&oq=The+Button+widget+is+a+standard+Tkinter+widget+used+to+implement+various+kinds+of+buttons.+Buttons+can+contain+text+or+images%2C+and+you+can+associate+a+Python+function+or+method+with+each+button.+When+the+button+is+pressed%2C+Tkinter+automatically+calls+that+function+or+method.&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.579j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and a search on Stack Overflow to see if maybe it was quoted elsewhere by accident, and it was not.

The closest thing I was able to find was [this](http://sandbox.effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm), which is not only a broken link but also according to google's summary of the webpage not an exact copy.

So why was the suggested edit rejected?

Comment: The first line is almost verbatim copied from https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_buttons.php

Comment: @Nick yes, but it wasn't my intention to blatantly copy off like that. And if it was, I would have linked the website as that edit was a month ago.

Comment: I didn't review it, I'm just saying that the _very first line, the first thing people will read,_ being almost word for word the same as an online source will push people towards the plagiarism rejection reason. First impressions and all that

Comment: Weird, Nick found one site where the first sentence is similar and I found one where the whole paragraph is identical to the one from an external source: https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/53078349.html (Topic "Tkinter button python 3"; second paragraph). No matter what your "intention" was, your text is not written by you, so it is correctly declined as plagiarism.

Comment: So, when you say "I maybe could have worded it better" ... do you suggest you originally wrote that text and someone else plagiarized it from you?

Comment: A quick Google search for each sentence results in several pages with the exact text. That's unequivocally plagiarism. Searches:  "[The Button widget is a standard Tkinter widget used to implement various kinds of buttons.](//www.google.com/search?q=%22The+Button+widget+is+a+standard+Tkinter+widget+used+to+implement+various+kinds+of+buttons.%22) [Buttons can contain text or images, and you can associate a Python function or method with each button.](//www.google.com/search?q=%22Buttons+can+contain+text+or+images%2C+and+you+can+associate+a+Python+function+or+method+with+each+button.%22) [cont]

Comment: [quote continued] [When the button is pressed, Tkinter automatically calls that function or method.](//www.google.com/search?q=%22When+the+button+is+pressed%2C+Tkinter+automatically+calls+that+function+or+method.%22)"

Comment: Since the link in my first comment looks like a scrapper result, I've digged a bit further and like Makyen found several sites all using the same text, like [this](https://archive.org/stream/Coding_Made_Simple_2016_UK/Coding_Made_Simple_2016_UK_djvu.txt), [this](https://brainly.com/question/17255585) and [this](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~hv/classes/MS/TkinterPres/), but since the scrapper has a bit more text there, they all don't look like the original source. Anyway, the old tag description was already plagiarized from the original tag creator, but no one noticed/checked that.

Comment: While I didn't take the time to try to track down the actual original place from which most of those sites copied, there are some in the search results which show dates substantially prior to your suggested edit. Are you claiming that you are the original author who posted it somewhere else from which all those sites copied? That's a fairly extraordinary claim, which requires evidence to be believed. It's *definitely* not something that reviewers would be looking for, *certainly* not with no such claim being mentioned in the edit comment (or in your question here).

Comment: “Now that was a month ago and looking back I maybe could have worded it better, but my main confusion lies in why it was rejected for plagiarism.” - As others have said the test was indeed copied verbatim from a website.  Just because the old tag description was plagiarized doesn’t mean the new description can be plagiarized.  **Searching for a whole sentence is fairly common practice when approving tag descriptions.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears *verbatim* on page 637 of *Comp-Computer Science-TB-12* by Reeta and Gagan Sahoo. It also appears in many other places on the Internet, as Makyen said, including [this website](http://www.owl.homeip.net/manuals/softdev/python/tkinter/button.htm).

Even if this is your original work that everyone else copied (not that this claim is believable to me in the slightest), the reviewers were wholly justified in rejecting this on the grounds that it *appears* to be plagiarized from external sources.

When doing a Google search to find exact text, it helps to wrap it in quotation marks; e.g.:
https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+Button+widget+is+a+standard+Tkinter+widget+used+to+implement+various+kinds+of+buttons.+Buttons+can+contain+text+or+images%2C+and+you+can+associate+a+Python+function+or+method+with+each+button.+When+the+button+is+pressed%2C+Tkinter+automatically+calls+that+function+or+method.%22

Comment: Ah, I see. I find it highly unlikely I would have plagiriazed it (at least on purpose) as I am a student who goes to school and I know the dangers of plagiarism. However it is copied word for word so that makes sense.

Comment: Right; I would have expected you to know better, which is why I find this somewhat confusing. But from the reviewers' perspective, it's not hard to understand what happened and why.

Comment: @10R You plagiarized it accidentally?