# What am I doing so wrong when I suggest things to SO? All of my ideas are terribly received

Tags: discussion, meta

I've noticed that every time I create a post here on Meta, it is badly received. Here are examples I haven't deleted for no reason:

- ["Suggested Edit Queue is Full" should be bypassed when going through First Post, Low Quality, and Help and Improvement queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406175/suggested-edit-queue-is-full-should-be-bypassed-when-going-through-first-post)
- [Does contributing to Review Queues help to lift a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405929/does-contributing-to-review-queues-help-to-lift-a-question-ban)
- [Have it show in search results if a question is a user's first post in SE network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406151/have-it-show-in-search-results-if-a-question-is-a-users-first-post-in-se-notwor)

They all have been *terribly* received, even after I proofread each of them and made sure they made good sense, but many users disagree with them (same post order as last list):

- (+3/-9) = -6 *Total** Score (total *80 views*), *7% DV/view*
- (+6/-16) = -10 *Total** Score (total *122 views), *9% DV/view*
- (+2/-30) = -28 *Total** Score (total *141 views*), *19% DV/view*

What am I doing *so terribly wrong* to cause so many of the total people to view to disagree?

Comment: For one, [Does contributing to Review Queues...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405929/522444) shows none of the fruits of your own research prior to asking the question. Why would you expect the meta site to react differently from the [main] main site in this regard?

Comment: Next, this, [Have it show in search results if a question is a user's first post in SE network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406151/522444) is simply a terrible suggestion

Comment: Your suggestions go against a lot of history on Meta Stack Overflow. For instance, the company added a "New contributor" badge to users new to Meta. This addition was quite poorly received by Meta regulars because we generally try and treat everyone the same; I vote to close questions by 100K rep users as quickly as questions by 100 rep users, if they are closeable. Adding a flag to search results similarly targets users rather than content.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree with most of that, but it was more just because a little pointer saying "Hey, this user might need some extra help" could benefit the community.

Comment: @CATboardBETA so.... " voting may indicate agreement or disagreement with the proposed change, in addition to the quality or usefulness of the post itself." (from the "feature-request" tag.  Is it simply possible people don't think your SUGGESTIONS are good, and downvote that? I personally don't think anyone is doing anything wrong when I downvote a feature request. I just... indicate I don't think the feature would be useful.

Comment: You probably want to read [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188)

Comment: First of all, you are not doing anything *terribly wrong* (just do a search for [feature-request] tag, sort by votes, and go to the last page), just that Meta does not like your suggestions (always remember - Meta sites as they are now are an afterthought, so the only clean way to voice agreement/disagreement we have at our disposal is voting) for a variety of reasons. Please, do read an amazingly on-point breakdown on [how to do FRs from Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/11407695) if you haven't done so before.

Comment: Just look through my questions and you'll see plenty of questions more downvoted than yours. [-13](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401307/i-dont-like-nice-tags), [-25](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398307/lets-make-stack-overflow-documentation-rise-again), and [-27](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404601/edit-was-rejected-even-though-it-doesnt-copy-from-an-external-source). It's a part of participating... everyone gets downvotes.

Comment: Also see [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/7296893), which is in the FAQ. Your feature requests all don't really show research.

Comment: I added the vote split for the three questions, feel free to rollback if you don't like the change.

Comment: It really does not help that your posts are written in such a way that there isn't much to do other than agree or disagree. For example, the [question ban review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405929/does-contributing-to-review-queues-help-to-lift-a-question-ban) boils down to "I don't know if it is as I want it, but if it isn't, it needs to be". There is almost nothing there that invites discussion or presents a position, it's just "I want" – so people vote to reply "I don't".

Comment: [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) will show you the score breakdown even if you don't have the reputation for it. It's a user script. You can see the code at greasyfork.org by pressing the "code" tab.

Comment: The thing you're doing wrong is thinking that with your little experience in curation of this site you can already suggest useful changes to the system.

Comment: @gnat That target doesn't seem appropriate; it's asking whether the way downvotes are used to express disagreement is a good idea. The OP is not asking that at all; they want to know why their own questions are not well received.

Comment: @CATboardBETA  the "little pointer" you are asking for is indeed right there for you and anyone else adding "feature-request" tag to their posts - tag Wiki https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info does explain expectations... If you are looking for proposal that would be well received - come up with sensible way to make people read those before <self censored> expressing mild disagreement with voting on their proposals.

Comment: @cigien consider that accepted answer here is essentially a summary of a top answser there (and please don't tell me that you are unaware that for last several years matters of duplicates are officially judged not by similarity of questions but by whether answers in the target address the question asked in the duplicate)

Comment: @gnat Then why have I denied it both times?The answer posted by [zcoop98](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11047824/zcoop98) still has much more specific to this question and me. Why do you think it got so many upvotes? Just because it was well written? You can't go to an SO question names "How can I sort an ArrayList in Java", and then answer it in C#.

Comment: Why do people disagree with me? is a sincere personal question but not a fruitful one on Meta because there isn't an answer independent of the reactions to your individual questions already discussed in their threads. Two things should seem positive: it's not personal or based on your reputation; if people are down-voting for either reason, that is utterly poor practice (but hard to monitor or police). Almost every practice here has some downsides as well as upsides but remains in place as better than alternatives.

Comment: The voting culture here really is absurd, in comparison to the main site. I have never seen even the most garbage questions on the main site get remotely as many downvotes as perfectly reasonable meta questions do routinely.

Comment: inexperienced askers often oppose duplicate closing because they [mistakenly believe that it is bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773)

Comment: @gnat Yes, I am aware that users close questions as duplicates when there are answers on the target that address the question (as you just did). As far as I'm aware, this is also an *incorrect* duplicate closure *unless* every possible answer on the target would work for the duplicate *and* vice-versa. If I'm wrong about this, could you point me at the Meta/s or other guidance that covers this? Especially since you called it *official*, they must exist.

Comment: @cigien official guidance is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773) and discussion particularly applicable for this specific case is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217401/165773)

Comment: This question is quite an ironic way of breaking your bad question streak.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Voting on meta is not absurd, it's passionate. Questions are kept around long after they've been beaten to death because knowing what's bad is essential to figuring out what's good. If you want passionate voting on Stack Overflow then I challenge you to write a question along the lines of "I think Java arrays should auto-sort when adding a new member to make things easier for people who cannot figure out the `.sort()` method." and brace yourself for a good flogging.

Comment: "What am I doing so wrong when I suggest things to SO? All of my ideas are terribly received" One possibility is that you might suggest the "wrong" things with wrong in the sense that a majority of people didn't agree with them.

Comment: As others are saying, if you aren't below -28, that's pretty good on Meta. IIR, I've posted a question or two that was quickly spiraling way below that, and so I deleted it. Meta isn't the most friendly place. Not a judgement, just an observation.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - at this point 19 upvotes, 15 downvotes - so at least 15 people are committed to keeping the streak alive.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `I have never in ten years seen a question on the main site get to -53` - I think that has been dismissed now. However, I wanted to add, I believe Meta has a more experienced and engaged community who are a) more likely to vote b) be more sure in their downvoting c) come from a much wider tag base

Comment: The trouble with opinions is you tend to get them when you ask for them..

Comment: @CaiusJard the same for honesty. Opinions and honesty combined make for one hefty package of personal responsibility.

Comment: Don't take it to heart, @CATboardBETA. You need to understand (and accept) that Stack Overflow Meta is pretty misanthropic. I love Stack Overflow (mostly), so I struggled for a long time with how I didn't really take to SO Meta. But they're simply not the same thing. In many ways, SO Meta is one of the worst aspects of SO. But it's not representative of Stack Overflow proper - and thank goodness. These days I mostly ignore SO Meta. Trust me, your Stack Overflow experience will almost certainly be better without it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Meta has a lot less traffic and *way* fewer posts than the main site. Furthermore, most posts on meta can be understood and commented on by most visitors, while posts on main require understanding the technologies used (unless its something that obviously needs to be closed, like spam). Posts on meta are more likely to be seen by someone who can judge whether the post is useful and/or whether they agree with a feature request.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

TL;DR – Two things:

1. Downvotes in general are aimed at your *content*, not you as the *author*, and especially on Meta feature requests, are used to indicate agreement/ disagreement with the request.
2. SO.Meta is very particular, and isn't at all shy about expressing disagreement or displeasure about an idea that it doesn't like or which it thinks is poorly thought out.

There are good reasons for most (one might even say the majority) of the generally accepted topical stances on Meta, and there's usually a lot of history backing them. That isn't to say that Meta is infallible – it certainly gets things wrong. It misses things, doesn't see all the details all the time, and is sometimes just downright stubborn regardless, but it *usually* has solid reasoning backing its claims.

So then, the real question is: **How do you avoid the vitriol of Meta when proposing something?**

[@Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617) to [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta), a meta post from some time ago that's still ever relevant today, does an *excellent* job of overviewing this among other commentary, and you should absolutely give it a read. In that post, he clearly outlines what an excellent feature request for meta should include; I've included an abridged version here for reference:

> 1. Clearly stated problem.
> 2. Proof(s) that the problem really exists and is worth addressing.
> 3. Summarized solution.
> 4. How you arrived at this solution, your thought process.
> 5. Details on solution where it matters (addressing edge cases).

Based on comments here and on your other posts, there seems to be consensus that your linked posts have failed to meet at least some of these points, largely by (perceived) lack of research. Don't forget to explain why your solution is needed at all (step 2) and how you came up with that particular solution (step 4). In the future, make sure to give real thought to all five of these pieces, not just to increase your request's chances of being positively received, but also to be certain that the problem you've identified even needs to be addressed at all.

That said, you should know that even with all the research in the world and the most eloquently crafted post, you'll still get downvotes sometimes. That's just how it goes; even the most well put together proposals won't always be well received, or will garner disagreement. Remember, at the end of the day: **votes aren't directed at *you***, and on Meta they're specifically used to indicate agreement or disagreement with *your request.* Don't take votes personally! Voters don't mean them personally, and you shouldn't take them that way. You'll save yourself a lot of grief by remembering this one, it's really important.

Further related reading:

- [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)
- [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375365/how-do-i-present-a-proposal-for-change-or-write-a-feature-request-for-stack-over)

Comment: Another often overlooked aspect of proposals for change that go down badly: *I have had this negative experience. Here is my proposal for y'all to accept that at best fixes my negative experience*. A sample size of one isn't a good basis to prove change is warranted.

Comment: Let's say that meta is extra critical and more prone to downvote - I for one think that people hit the downvote button when on the main site they would refrain from voting for example. "Zero vote" does not really exist on meta. And I for one think that is actually a good thing because when something is positively scored on meta, you can be almost positive it's a really good thing that should not be ignored.

Comment: "does an excellent job of overviewing this among other commentary, and you should absolutely give it a read. In that post, he clearly outlines what an excellent feature request for meta should include; I've included an abridged version here for reference:" Disagreed. I sincerely feel that typical heavily-downvoted questions here include all of these elements, and it doesn't help in the slightest. That's what I see every time I come here, anyway.

Comment: @Karl I think it depends a lot on the topic too. There are certain topics that strike a nerve on meta (eg. see [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)) which, no matter how well-researched, will perhaps never receive positive feedback. I also have no intention of saying that *all* well researched proposals *should* be implemented, posts that shouldn't will receive downvotes too.

Comment: This answer is good useful general advice, but I would have expected a few more details in which way the linked example questions are deficient.

Comment: As a user who has posted some horribly received Meta questions and some greatly received ones, I've found the trick is not to be too specific. A question like "This specific review task is incorrect" is more likely to be downvoted than "Should comments be counted as a downvote?"

Comment: And with meta not only do you have the more experienced and vocal/engaged members, you have members from a much wider tag base than would ordinarily see a given question on SO. I find voting on meta a much better weather (weather warning for site) vane.

Answer (score 15):

### Downvotes are disagreement, not rating

Various comments and the other answer hint at this but don't quite spell it out: the meaning of a downvote is completely different on Meta and SO. For feature requests, discussions etc in particular:

- SO: "This question is bad"
- Meta: "I disagree with the view expressed in this question"

So, a score of -10 doesn't necessarily mean something has gone terribly wrong - it just means your view is in the minority.

Comment: I understand this, I meant more why are my ideas so terribly bad. didn't do a good job titling.

Comment: This is often stated, but a new user would be forgiven for not knowing this, since the tooltips over the voting buttons still say something like "this question is unclear shows no effort, sucks etc", rather than "This is an interesting useful suggestion showing effort but I disagree with the proposal and I vote against it".  I understand that from a "UX" perspective, this is probably an oversight due to the fact that the former description applies to every non-Meta forum on the site, and is probably a fixed string in the code. Though I'm sure it could be fixed for Meta if one really wanted to.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - you might be interested in [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353758/11407695) stuck in [meta-tag:status-review] hell for 4 years (off-note: in [meta-tag:status-planned] -> [meta-tag:status-review] to be precise).

Comment: @CATboardBETA I'm saying, your ideas may not be "terribly bad", just unpopular. They're really not the same thing. I don't think there's anything wrong with suggesting ideas that are mostly not popular - occasionally you will have a good idea that is valuable.

Answer (score 15):

What you're doing wrong in those questions is the following:

- [Have it show in search results if a question is a user's first post in SE network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406151/have-it-show-in-search-results-if-a-question-is-a-users-first-post-in-se-notwor)

This is a blatant duplicate of an existing suggestion, which implies you failed to do research, which is a no-no on Meta. Meta users are the hardest core of Stack Overflow, which means we are far less tolerant of failure to do research.

- ["Suggested Edit Queue is Full" should be bypassed when going through First Post, Low Quality, and Help and Improvement queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406175/suggested-edit-queue-is-full-should-be-bypassed-when-going-through-first-post) and [Does contributing to Review Queues help to lift a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405929/does-contributing-to-review-queues-help-to-lift-a-question-ban)

You're presenting your suggestion (opinion) as a fact/something that "needs" to be implemented. That's not suggesting, that's demanding, and Meta - as a platform for **discussing** suggestions - is understandably hostile to demands. Wording these questions in a more neutral manner, i.e. actually as suggestions, would have resulted in a more positive response.

- With all three questions, you're taking feedback way too personally. Of course *you* think your suggestion is great, but you are only one person; the point of discussing that suggestion here is to draw upon the aggregated thousands of hours of experience of all of Meta's users, and the odds are good that a decent proportion of said users will disagree with that suggestion. In short, if you're going to throw a suggestion to the Meta wolves, you've got to be prepared for the possibility that we wolves are going to tear it apart.

I've personally submitted Meta suggestions that have garnered hundreds of upvotes; I've also submitted some that have received dozens of downvotes. Yes, the latter stings a bit and probably always will, but paradoxically I've found that it's helped me to divorce my ego from my suggestions - which I believe has helped me to make better suggestions. I still put my heart and soul into what I'm suggesting, but I don't allow my heart to be broken if that suggestion is rejected by Meta.

Always remember: it's not about you; it's about what Meta thinks will be best for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Great personal feedback. Take away message: wording matters a lot. For example: bad (We should do X), okay (Should we do X?), good (Would X be a good solution to Y?), best (What should be done about Y if anything? - and present X in an answer).

Answer (score 8):

> I understand this, I meant more why are my ideas so terribly bad

I quote from the comments on Steve Bennett's answer. I am going to rephrase this because this is a little too negative for its own good:

*"Why are my ideas not good enough?"*

There, now we can talk about it. Excellent question. You are not alone I can tell you. Mine aren't either and I've been hanging around here for years.

Making suggestions for change to Stack Overflow intimidates me. Doesn't it do that to you? I'll explain why: I have been part of teams to build websites myself, I've done the job, I know what is involved. I have never built Stack Overflow or a website of similar scale, though. Not in the 25-ish years I've been doing this job. I know where I would begin to design such a site, but I would have many insecurities when presenting the design to other people because I've just not done it before and frankly I don't know anyone that has. I have trouble seeing the big picture, what needs to be done to maintain realistic performance and to keep the site from turning into an unusable mess. Sites that support hundreds of people or maybe even thousands, sure. But *millions*? Google tells me that Stack Overflow has over 50 million active users each month. **whistles**. That's on another level.

let's create an analogy. Stack Overflow is like a flipping huge beehive. Except that it isn't, because bees have the ability to communicate with each other through chemical signals to keep order in the chaos. We cannot, we are mostly detached from each other when we do our things on the site. So, we need different methods to maintain order. And maintaining order where millions of people are involved... that is a very hard necessity because otherwise Stack Overflow would collapse under its own success. Order implies setting boundaries and limitations, people really don't like limitations and will be inclined to rebel against them. Current affairs (2020, 2021) prove that worldwide. Difficulty level: over 9000. Not only do you need to set the boundaries and limitations, but somehow they must also be made palatable.

And therein lies the rub. Making suggestions that actually have a chance of succeeding in the Stack Overflow arena (read: they don't have a detrimental butterfly effect) can be very hard. For most of us making suggestions for change is to learn how we are wrong, lack knowledge or are subjected to tunnel vision. We have to learn to see beyond our own personal emotional experience with the site and be the neutral architect instead. Say that a change is implemented. How does that affect the millions of people using the site? How will it affect the performance of the site? How will it affect the quality of content, both old and new? How can the effect of the change be measured so we might know it benefits or is detrimental? How feasible is it to make such a change in an existing very mature site? Can it be done in weeks, or will it take a huge effort?

That's a long journey involving a trail of downvoted meta posts along the way. It is, pretty much, inevitable unless you are privileged enough to be part of engineering projects that give you the experience and insight to take a shortcut. Probably you will just want to wear the downvoted meta posts with a badge of honor and be satisfied with the idea that when you know enough you probably will write that stellar suggestion that receives hundreds of upvotes. Some day...

TL;DR - are you really doing anything wrong? Not if you're learning from it!

Comment: *bees have the ability to communicate with each other through chemical signals*. I did fart in your direction. Didn't you notice?

Comment: @rene smells like flowers! Missed opportunity to make it a Holy Grail reference.

Answer (score 6):

Let's go through your points one by one:

> They all have been terribly received

Frankly, they were not: if you take a look at the score<sup>0</sup>, it just shows that more people disagree with you than agree. Only [one of the proposals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406151) was met with strong negativity, but you stroke a bare nerve by proposing something very similar to the "new contributor" policy (strongly [criticized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/786798)<sup>1</sup>).

> even after I proofread each of them

That is certainly nice, but does not guarantee you a good reception (just like a proofread academic paper does not guarantee good peer reviews). Having a proposal that is easy to read helps, but is not a substitute for a good proposal.

> made sure they made good sense

There is a small part missing at the end: "to me". What is one man's trash is another man's treasure. People differ in experience, worldview and have strong opinions on a lot of matters (especially on Meta), so even if the proposed change makes perfect sense to you, it can turn out that not everyone shares your notion of what's good for the site.

> What am I doing so terribly wrong to cause so many of the total people to view to disagree?

Apart from what has already been said, there is at least one more point: **missing data**. It is true that feature requests come from a personal experience, but at a scale of Stack Overflow, most FRs have to show the problem is *widespread enough* to be addressed in the first place.

StackExchange Data Explorer ([SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)) is a good place to start when drafting a proposal: not only data analysis makes requests look professional, it also helps steering the conversation towards constructive discussion (as your claims become *verifiable*).

---

<sup>0</sup> I know you could not do that by yourself until a high-rep user stepped in, which is yet another case against having real post scores hidden from users without the ["established user"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege.

<sup>1</sup> Before thinking: "but the announcement is upvoted!", please take a read through the answers.

Comment: IMO meta posts should have the vote counts visible for everyone and not just established users, but that is a topic for another post

Comment: @MarcSances - agreed, I think *all* posts should have vote scores visible regardless of the status. I haven't been under 1K on SO for quite a while now, and on Uber Meta, for example, it makes me feel like I am being blindfolded. There is an [old explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318306) that this saves on DB queries, but I am not sure it is worth hiding the truth from new-ish users (which are also sometimes experienced users with new accounts)

Comment: Case in point - the linked post on Uber Meta about introducing a "new contributor" indicator. Surely at +93 this a great feature everyone agrees with? But if one takes a look at the [real vote count](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1390087/view-count-of-a-post-on-meta-stackexchange?ID=314287), it is actually polarizing with +314/-220 respective votes (as of last Sunday).

Comment: Since this keeps coming up, I should mention that the privilege restriction on viewing vote counts isn't a fundamental restriction, i.e. unlike most privileges that are granted because you're trusted, this one is simply a "treat"; it's to have something to look forward to upon reaching 1k :) There are plenty of workarounds for this; I use the [userscript here](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082), which lets you see view counts everywhere, not just Meta.

Comment: @cigien - I know, it is a treat, but it also skews the real perception of how the post is really received (anyways, I don't think it is worth debating it though), just voicing my opinion of it whenever possible :) All the workarounds are nice, of course, but it still would be nice to see this is as a core feature (not likely to happen, though, I understand that).

Comment: Sure, I agree it would be nice to have it as a core feature. Make sure to vote on these [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97892) [requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82442) among others, if you haven't done so already. Maybe it'll get implemented one day.

Comment: @cigien - yeah... Anyways, thanks for the links, good additions to the collection of posts to refer to.

Comment: my point on why vote counts should be visible in Meta is to give everyone more feedback on why their posts have a low or negative score. Since score in Meta feature requests is actually like votes, it is way more important for the user to know how many favorable and unfavorable votes he has. It is not the same 0 score with 3 votes for and 3 votes against (not enough visibility of the request), than 0 score with 35 votes for and 35 votes against (which means there is no consensus in the community with the requested feature)